# Higher waterpressure through one 40mm pipe or two 32mm pipes?

Tags: water, water-pressure

I have a small field I need to water, it is 100m away from my water outlet.
My water pressure is somewhere around 1.5bar. I have two options to connect the sprinkler on the field:

A. 40mm pipe (40mm is outer diameter, wall thickness is 3.7mm)

B. two 32mm pipes connected in parallel (30mm with 3mm wall thickness)

Which solution will give a higher water pressure at the sprinkler?

[image]

Comment: With no flow the static water pressure will be nearly the same.

Comment: Are you looking for higher pressure, or a higher flow rate?

Comment: I'd lean toward the larger pipe. Have to calc it out, but you're not picking up all that much cross-sectional area with the two smaller pipes, and you do pick up a lot in the way of edge effects: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/reynold-number-water-flow-pipes-d_574.html

Comment: thank you, I am looking for a higher pressure at the sprinkler, so that a larger area can be watered with the sprinkler standing in one position.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger thank you for the link, definitely something I will check out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given volume of water per second, the two 32mm pipes will have a lower pressure loss than the single 40mm pipe.

Using the head loss calculator at http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/hazen-williams-water-d_797.html, and assuming you're using PVC pipe, I found the following pressure losses. Each line gives the flow rate, the loss for a single 40mm pipe, and the loss for two 32mm pipes:

- 0 liters/second: 0.0 kPa and 0.0 kPa (obviously)
- 0.1 liters/second: 0.3 kPa and 0.2 kpa
- 0.2 liters/second: 1.0 kPa and 0.8 kPa
- 0.5 liters/second: 5.6 kPa and 4.6 kPa
- 1.0 liters/second: 20.1 kPa and 16.5 kPa
- 2.0 liters/second: 72.5 kPa and 59.4 kPa

And, just in case you're an avid XKCD reader, if you're [running Niagara Falls through your pipes](http://what-if.xkcd.com/147/):

- 2831684.7 liters/second: 1.78 x 10^13 kPa and 1.46 x 10^13 kPa

(1.46 x 10^13 kPa is 40,000 times the pressure at the center of the Earth, or about the pressure at the center of the Sun. Moral of this story: don't try running Niagara Falls through your pipes.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer and the link to the calculator.